# on image hover show div and hide the div on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying show a list of data in a table where when the user hovers the icon a small div appears below the icon which gives some links.

The problem that im having is when the image is hovered the hidden div appears but disappears before i try to click on that div. i need that div to hide when i take the mouse out of the div.

And also when i hover the div pushes the content down. How can i keep it in away that it doesnt push the content?

JS

```
$('.bubble').hide();

$("#bu tr td img").hover(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".bubble").first().show();
}, function(){
    $(this).nextAll(".bubble").first().hide();
});
```

HTML

```
<table id="bu">
<tr>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td><img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/113776/screenshots/1338903/explore_icons_designed_by_mandar_apte_studio_for_lurnq_6_1x.png" style="width:30px" />
  <div class="bubble">
  <a>Test</a>
  <br>
  <a>test</a>
  </div>

  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td><img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/113776/screenshots/1338903/explore_icons_designed_by_mandar_apte_studio_for_lurnq_6_1x.png" style="width:30px" />
  <div class="bubble">
  <a>Test</a>
  <br>
  <a>test</a>
  </div>

  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Data Input</td>
  <td><img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/113776/screenshots/1338903/explore_icons_designed_by_mandar_apte_studio_for_lurnq_6_1x.png" style="width:30px" />
  <div class="bubble">
  <a>Test</a>
  <br>
  <a>test</a>
  </div>

  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Data Test</td>
  <td><img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/113776/screenshots/1338903/explore_icons_designed_by_mandar_apte_studio_for_lurnq_6_1x.png" style="width:30px" />
  <div class="bubble">
  <a>Test</a>
  <br>
  <a>test</a>
  </div>

  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have created a fiddle over here https://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/qks2vdpv/2/

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You don't need JS like everyone else said but I added some additional positioning so the rest of the elements don't shift on hover.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="bu">
<tr>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td class="image"><img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/113776/screenshots/1338903/explore_icons_designed_by_mandar_apte_studio_for_lurnq_6_1x.png" style="width:30px" />
  <div class="bubble">
  <a>Test</a>
  <br>
  <a>test</a>
  </div>

  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td class="image"><img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/113776/screenshots/1338903/explore_icons_designed_by_mandar_apte_studio_for_lurnq_6_1x.png" style="width:30px" />
  <div class="bubble">
  <a>Test</a>
  <br>
  <a>test</a>
  </div>

  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Data Input</td>
  <td class="image"><img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/113776/screenshots/1338903/explore_icons_designed_by_mandar_apte_studio_for_lurnq_6_1x.png" style="width:30px" />
  <div class="bubble">
  <a>Test</a>
  <br>
  <a>test</a>
  </div>

  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Data Test</td>
  <td class="image"><img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/113776/screenshots/1338903/explore_icons_designed_by_mandar_apte_studio_for_lurnq_6_1x.png" style="width:30px" />
  <div class="bubble">
  <a>Test</a>
  <br>
  <a>test</a>
  </div>

  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image {
  position: relative;
}
.image:hover .bubble {
  display: block;
}
.bubble {
  display: none;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.bubble:after
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 15px 15px;
border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
margin-left: -15px;
top: -15px;
left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Works great :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without the use of Javascript:

```css
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display:none;
}

.bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 15px 15px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  left: 50%;
}

td:nth-child(2):hover .bubble {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<table id="bu">
   <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>
         <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/113776/screenshots/1338903/explore_icons_designed_by_mandar_apte_studio_for_lurnq_6_1x.png" style="width:30px" />
         <div class="bubble">
            <a>Test</a>
            <br>
            <a>test</a>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>
         <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/113776/screenshots/1338903/explore_icons_designed_by_mandar_apte_studio_for_lurnq_6_1x.png" style="width:30px" />
         <div class="bubble">
            <a>Test</a>
            <br>
            <a>test</a>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Data Input</td>
      <td>
         <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/113776/screenshots/1338903/explore_icons_designed_by_mandar_apte_studio_for_lurnq_6_1x.png" style="width:30px" />
         <div class="bubble">
            <a>Test</a>
            <br>
            <a>test</a>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Data Test</td>
      <td>
         <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/113776/screenshots/1338903/explore_icons_designed_by_mandar_apte_studio_for_lurnq_6_1x.png" style="width:30px" />
         <div class="bubble">
            <a>Test</a>
            <br>
            <a>test</a>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all class `.bubble` opened before show the right once.

```
$('.bubble').hide(); 

$("#bu tr td img").mouseover(function() {
    $(".bubble").hide(); // <-- this 
    $(this).nextAll(".bubble").first().show();
});
```

You can use `display: none` on your css and remove your first line.